# How to change the y axis of a histogram so it's a density function in r?

Tags: r, histogram, density-plot

How is it possible that I can change a normal histogram in a way that the x-axis indicates not absolute numbers but the relative numbers, the density?

This is what my histogram looks like now:

```
hist(df$rent, xlim = c(0, 36), ylim = c(0, 300), breaks = 30)
```

Comment: `plot(density(1:100))`

Comment: @dario Where am I supposed to put that in my code?

Comment: No it actually works pretty easy with the argument freq = FALSE

Answer (score 1):

To add the argument

```
freq = FALSE
```

is the solution

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: freq = FALSE works well and results in columns whose areas are in proportion to the relative frequencies in the classes.

is there a simple way to make the y-axis show the absolute rather than the relative density, i.e. get columns whose areas are in proportion to the absolute counts in the classes?